# TikZ in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, tikz

R Markdown is a good tool for document authoring. It can use LaTeX statement in R Markdown directory. But when I try to insert a Ti*k*Z picture, I am lost about how to add preamble `\usepackage{tikz}` in it, so compile will fail.

Example code:

```
---
title: "R Markdown with tikz picture"
author: "Me"
date: "January 10, 2015"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## TikZ picture
- Here is a TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Since actually it will generate a LaTeX document, so it's fine to just add it in LaTeX and then compile it to PDF but I wish I can just do it in R Markdown, then click the "Knit to PDF" button to generate PDF document directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown) it is described how to use LaTeX packages in R Markdown. Not sure if the tikz-package works with R Markdown though.

Comment: Great,it's what I want.Need to add section in YAML: header-includes:
   - \usepackage{tikz}

Comment: @Beatlej: Did it work to use the tikz package with RMarkdown?

Comment: @histelheim Sure, check a simple example from my answer below.

Comment: I am now using `tikzDevice` (via `knitr::chunk_options$set(dev = "tikz")`) in an `rmarkdown` document that builds as a PDF. It *just works*, the above line was enough, everything else seems to happen magically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 20):

This is a example about how to use tikz graph in R Markdown within R Studio

```
---
title: "Hello World"
author: "Me"
date: "February 17, 2015"
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usepackage{pgfplots}
---

## TikZ picture
- Here is a TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

- Here is another TikZ picutre

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymax=9, samples=50]
  \addplot[blue, ultra thick] (x,x*x);
  \addplot[red,  ultra thick] (x*x,x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why when we knit to html, this tikz figures are not compiled??

Comment: @David This is an old question, but are you compiling your file as a PDF file? If you are, then there should not be any issue. You seem to be trying to compile your file as an HTML file.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS Yeah..Thats a mistake. I didnt realize that knit html does not use latex but tikz needs latex to compile