# Using tikz in html_document using RMarkdown

Tags: r, svg, r-markdown, tikz

**Question:** *Is there a way to use tikz notation within an Rmarkdown document without having to compile the document to a pdf?*

And (sort of in the same direction):

**Question:** *What is the best way to add mutiple tikz graphics in an RMarkdown document that I want to compile to html (while keeping the flexibilty to compile the file to pdf or word in a later stage as well)?*

I've read many answers to posts (like [TikZ in R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880563/tikz-in-r-markdown) or [How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics)) that ask similar questions but I am still not completely sure, hence the questions.

I basically want to run this piece of code

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{tikz}
---

## TikZ picture

Some picture

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Instead of `pdf_document` I'd like to have `html_document` + some magic that automatically converts the tikz graphic to something that can be understood by html. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just discovered that you can add tikz code in the code chunk of Rmarkdown when you modify the engine option :

````
---
output: html_document
---

Some picture

```{r,engine='tikz'}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

The problem is that the figure is pixelized and the scale is not respected. One way to solve this may be to change the extension of the figure output (to pdf) and the width and the height with the chunk options (e.g. equals to 3 inches) :

````
```{r,engine='tikz',fig.ext='pdf',fig.width=3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

I'm sure there are better solutions but it's an easy way to use tikz code for an html output.

Comment: hmm I cant get any of the two examples to work. have you tested them? What version of R and knitr are you using?

Comment: Are you using R on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Both example work fine in my personal Mac computer (I use R 3.3.2 and knit 1.15.1). However I've tested it on a Windows computer and it didn't work (with the same configuration). I'll tell you if I found why. I don't know if you have to install a program, like GhostScript for svg output (see [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/1177))

Comment: Ok thanks. I am using Windows. I have GhostScript but maybe something else is required

Comment: Have you tried with the parameter `fig.ext='svg'` ?

Comment: @AQLT I use Windows and using `fig.ext = 'svg'` works perfectly for me. Thank you very much.